# grep output to show only matching file

Tags: grep

What is the option for `grep` that will allow me only to print the matching file and not the line within a file that matches the criteria?

Comment: I typically only use this command when searching for files that call a specific function or method.

Comment: use case (search and replace foo->bar in all files recursively):  
    sed -i 's/foo/bar/' \`grep -lR 'foo'\`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I use grep to show just filenames (no in-line matches) on linux?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6637882/how-can-i-use-grep-to-show-just-filenames-no-in-line-matches-on-linux)

Answer (score 407, accepted):

```
grep -l
```

(That's a lowercase L)

Comment: [Letter O Considered Harmful](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fortran#Humor)

Answer (score 53):

You can use the Unix-style `-l` switch – typically terse and cryptic – or the equivalent `--files-with-matches` – longer and more readable.

The output of `grep --help` is not easy to read, but it's there:

```
-l, --files-with-matches  print only names of FILEs containing matches
```

Answer (score 30):

`-l` (that's a lower-case L).

Answer (score 4):

Also remember one thing. Very important.
You have to specify the command something like this to be more precise
`grep -l "pattern" *`