# How can I use grep to show just filenames on Linux?

Tags: linux, grep

How can I use [grep](https://linux.die.net/man/1/grep) to show just file-names (no in-line matches) on Linux?

I am usually using something like:

```
find . -iname "*php" -exec grep -H myString {} \;
```

How can I just get the file-names (with paths), but without the matches? Do I have to use [xargs](https://linux.die.net/man/1/xargs)? I didn't see a way to do this on my grep man page.

Comment: You mean, you want the filenames that have at least one match?

Comment: Great question. I actually started using this to open a list of files returned by grep in Vim. `vim $(grep -rl Something app/)`

Comment: You cannot list files using grep command, it is basically used to fetch desired text from a file or a list. For instance, ps aux | grep 'apt-get'                       or grep 'text-to-find' /path/to/file/

Comment: @iamjayp Ummm, you can too list files using the grep command. `grep -lr 'text-to-find' ./*` works quite nicely!

Comment: @AndriySimonov I'm not against having it here (and there is a gazillion precedence of grep questions) but it probably belongs technically to SuperUser or Ubuntu or so. To Ryan: I'm surprised it was closed instead of being migrated.

Comment: @Peter Moderators can only migrate questions that are less than 60 days old. Therefore, for old questions that are nevertheless off-topic here because they're not about programming, closing them is our only option. I feel strongly that such questions should not be *deleted*, because that is destructive of value, but reopening them also makes no sense because it sets a bad example to users who are unaware that SO limits themselves only to programming questions.

Comment: I'm voting to reopen this question because IMO, the author is attempting to use shell scripting (albeit a pretty simple one-liner script) to accomplish a common programming task. Even though there's overlap with SU and U&L sites, overlap doesn't exclude this question from being asked here on SO. IMO, this question does fall within the SO guidelines.

Answer (score 2252, accepted):

The standard option `grep -l` (that is a lowercase L) could do this.

From the [Unix standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xcu/grep.html):

```
-l
    (The letter ell.) Write only the names of files containing selected
    lines to standard output. Pathnames are written once per file searched.
    If the standard input is searched, a pathname of (standard input) will
    be written, in the POSIX locale. In other locales, standard input may be
    replaced by something more appropriate in those locales.
```

You also do not need `-H` in this case.

Comment: -H also shows the matches themselves. The question was for just filenames.

Comment: @Hauke And my answer was -l. I mentioned -H only because the user's command in the question included -H and it is redundant when -l is given.

Comment: Nice, I personally like using this with other flags `grep -nrl "some text" .` when looking for text in a set of subfolders recursively

Comment: What's the mnemonic for ell?

Comment: "fi**L**es with matches"

Comment: I thought this wasn't the answer, because it says "The scanning will stop on the first match." but I guess this means scanning *within the file* will stop, not that it stops after finding one file.

Answer (score 199):

From the `grep(1)` man page:

> ```
>   -l, --files-with-matches
>           Suppress  normal  output;  instead  print the name of each input
>           file from which output would normally have  been  printed.   The
>           scanning  will  stop  on  the  first match.  (-l is specified by
>           POSIX.)
> ```

Comment: Stopping at the first match is necessary and nature .

Comment: the documentation makes it a bit unclear. "The scanning will stop on the first match" - indicates that all file names will be printed, but the scanning for the matching word will stop at the first occurence.

Comment: @VishalP: Since we don't care where the occurrences are, only that they exist, there is no point in searching each file beyond the first occurrence.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Exactly. The first impression of the document makes you feel that it will only print the file name of the first file. You really need a couple of reads to understand it.

Comment: 'The scanning of the current file will stop on the first match.' would be much clearer.

Comment: [GNU grep man page](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html)  clarifies this.

Comment: And how about `pdfgrep`?

Answer (score 86):

For a simple file search, you could use grep's `-l` and `-r` options:

```
grep -rl "mystring"
```

All the search is done by grep. Of course, if you need to select files on some other parameter, [find](http://linux.die.net/man/1/grep) is the correct solution:

```
find . -iname "*.php" -execdir grep -l "mystring" {} +
```

The `execdir` option builds each grep command per each directory, and concatenates filenames into only one command (`+`).