# How can I "grep" for a filename instead of the contents of a file?

Tags: grep

[grep](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grep) is used to search within a file to see if any line matches a given regular expression. However, I have this situation - I want to write a regular expression that will match the filename itself (and not the contents of the file). I will run this from the system's root directory, to find all those files that match the regular expression.

For example, if I want to find all [Visual Basic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic) form files that start with an "f" and end with .frm, I'll use the regular expression -

```
   "f[[:alnum:]]*\.frm"
```

Can grep do this? If not, is there a utility that would let me do this?

Comment: The must be a lot of duplicates from the first nearly four years.

Comment: ***Not*** a duplicate (controlling the output from grep (independent of the matching, etc.)): *[How can I use grep to show just filenames on Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6637882/how-can-i-use-grep-to-show-just-filenames-on-linux)*

Comment: This question is a duplicate of [How can I recursively find all files in current and subfolders based on wildcard matching?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5905054/11725753)

Comment: @PeterMortensen the irony is by closing this and commenting you successfully put this into the first page of google results for this kind of question.

Answer (score 163, accepted):

You need to use `find` instead of `grep` in this case.

You can also use `find` in combination with `grep` or `egrep`:

```
$ find | grep "f[[:alnum:]]\.frm"
```

Comment: This is unnecessary. Find has that functionality built-in with the `-regex` option.

Comment: it is unnecessary here, but grep supports perl regex whereas find does not.

Comment: @alpha_989, I said grep supports it, which it does: https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/html_node/grep-Programs.html#grep-Programs  point is piping to grep is only needed if you need pcre. whereswalden has the right answer

Comment: @RM: No, that still searches file contents. It just *prints* file names instead of printing the matching lines.

Answer (score 129):

**Example**

```
find <path> -name '*FileName*'
```

**From manual:**

*find -name pattern*

Base  of  file  name  (the  path  with  the  leading directories removed) matches shell pattern pattern.
Because the leading directories are removed, the file names considered for a match with -name will never
include a slash, so "-name a/b" will never match anything (you probably need to use -path instead).  The
metacharacters ("*", "?", and "[]") match a "." at the start of the base name (this is a change in find‐
utils-4.2.2;  see  section  STANDARDS CONFORMANCE below).  To ignore a directory and the files under it,
use -prune; see an example in the description of -path.  Braces are not  recognised  as  being  special,
despite  the fact that some shells including Bash imbue braces with a special meaning in shell patterns.
The filename matching is performed with the use of the fnmatch(3) library function.    Don't  forget  to
enclose the pattern in quotes in order to protect it from expansion by the shell.

Comment: I found this answer to be the most useful. I added a couple of additional options:  `find . -maxdepth 1 -name "*filename*" -print`

Comment: @JSONC11 that is very useful, thank you!

Answer (score 60):

As Pablo said, you need to use `find` instead of `grep`, but there's no need to pipe `find` to `grep`. `find` has that functionality built in:

```
find . -regex 'f[[:alnum:]]\.frm'
```

`find` is a very powerful program for searching for files by name and supports searching by file type, depth limiting, combining different search terms with boolean operations, and executing arbitrary commands on found files. See [the find man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find) for more information.

Comment: I would add the very handy feature of find to search by date with `-mtime` and `-mmin`

Comment: Also, -regex switch performs matches with the whole path.
So to work the example needs to add .* at the regex beginning.

Answer (score 25):

The easiest way is

```
find . | grep test
```

Here *find* will list all the files in the (.), i.e., the
current directory, recursively.

And then it is just a simple grep. All the files which name has "test" will appear.

You can play with *grep* as per your requirement.
Note: As the grep is a generic string classification. It can result in giving you not only file names. But if a path has a directory ('/xyz_test_123/other.txt') it would also be part of the result set.

Comment: This will find anything with "test" in the path, e.g. `./foo/bar/latest/fred.txt`.

Comment: oh. That one i didn't think of.
Thank you for mentioning.

Comment: this helped me to quickly find the "*.abc" vs "*.ABC" formats

Comment: I tried the tree answer above this, but with copying, e.g. `find . -name '*.json' -print0 | grep -z 'vs' | sort -z | xargs -0 cp -t ../vs` it errors on the branch char's. `cp: failed...'├── .': No such file...`  Your answer resulted in the above solution!  (What's the 0's and -z's? Look up null-terminated output/strings.)

Answer (score 23):

You can find the relative path of a file using tree. Just pipe the output to grep to filter down:

```
tree -f | grep filename
```

Here is a function you can put into your `.bash_profile`, `.bashrc`, `.zshrc` or other...

```
findfile(){ tree -f | grep $1; } # $1 = filename, -f is full path
```

Comment: -f is optional.

Answer (score 14):

```
find -iname "file_name"

Syntax:
find -type type_descriptor file_name_here
```

*type_descriptor* types:

f: regular file

d: directory

l: symbolic link

c: character devices

b: block devices

Comment: I cannot seem to use a filename following the `-type typedescriptor` alone. Is this a mistake?

Answer (score 6):

```
find . | grep KeywordToSearch
```

Here `.` means the current directory which is the value for the *path* parameter for the [find](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Find_(Unix)) command. It is piped to grep to search the keyword which should return all matching results.

Note: This is case sensitive. So for example `fileName` and `FileName` are not same.

Answer (score 4):

You can also do:

```
tree | grep filename
```

This pipes the output of the tree command to grep for a search. This will only tell you whether the file exists though.

Answer (score -1):

Also for multiple files.

```
tree /path/to/directory/ | grep -i "file1 \| file2 \| file3"
```

Answer (score -3):

No, grep works just fine for this:

```
 grep -rl "filename" [starting point]

 grep -rL "not in filename"
```

Comment: This searches file contents for "filename", then prints the names of files with matches. OP wants match file names, not file contents.

Comment: Agreed, this doesn't search filenames, it just prints the names of the filenames for which it's found *content* matches. You've misunderstood both the `-l` and `-L` options considerably.