# How to get only filenames without Path by using grep

Tags: linux, bash, grep

I have got the following Problem.

I´m doing a grep like:

$command =    grep -r -i --include=*.cfg 'host{' /omd/sites/mesh/etc/icinga/conf.d/objects

I got the following output:

```
/omd/sites/mesh/etc/icinga/conf.d/objects/testsystem/test1.cfg:define host{
/omd/sites/mesh/etc/icinga/conf.d/objects/testsystem/test2.cfg:define host{
/omd/sites/mesh/etc/icinga/conf.d/objects/testsystem/test3.cfg:define host{
...
```

for all *.cfg files.

With `exec($command,$array)`

I passed the result in an array.

Is it possible to get only the filenames as result of the grep-command.

I have tried the following:

```
$Command=    grep -l -H -r -i --include=*.cfg 'host{' /omd/sites/mesh/etc/icinga/conf.d/objects
```

but I got the same result.

I know that on the forum a similar topic exists.([How can I use grep to show just filenames (no in-line matches) on linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6637882/how-can-i-use-grep-to-show-just-filenames-no-in-line-matches-on-linux)), but the solution doesn´t work.

With "exec($Command,$result_array)" I try to get an array with the results.
The mentioned solutions works all, but I can´t get an resultarray with exec().

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yet another simpler solution:

```
grep -l whatever-you-want | xargs -L 1 basename
```

or you can avoid `xargs` and use a subshell instead, if you are not using an ancient version of the GNU coreutils:

```
basename -a $(grep -l whatever-you-want)
```

`basename` is the bash straightforward solution to get a file name without path. You may also be interested in `dirname` to get the path only.

[GNU Coreutils basename documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/basename-invocation.html)

Answer (score 5):

> Is it possible to get only the filenames as result of the `grep` command.

With `grep` you need the `-l` option to display only file names.

Using `find ... -execdir grep ... \{} +` you might prevent displaying the full path of the file (is this what you need?)

```
find /omd/sites/mesh/etc/icinga/conf.d/objects -name '*.cfg' \
     -execdir grep -r -i -l 'host{' \{} +
```

---

In addition, concerning the second part of your question, to **read the result of a command into an array**, you have to use the syntax: `IFS=$'\n' MYVAR=( $(cmd ...) )`

In that particular case (I formatted as multiline statement in order to clearly show the structure of that expression -- of course you could write as a "one-liner"):

```
IFS=$'\n' MYVAR=(
    $(
        find objects -name '*.cfg' \
                     -execdir grep -r -i -l 'host{' \{} +
    )
)
```

You have then access to the result in the array `MYVAR` as usual. While I while I was testing (3 matches in that particular case):

```
sh$ echo ${#MYVAR[@]}
3
sh$ echo ${MYVAR[0]}
./x y.cfg
sh$ echo ${MYVAR[1]}
./d.cfg
sh$ echo ${MYVAR[2]}
./e.cfg
# ...
```

Comment: Your suggested string works! Thank you. I have got one more question: -I try to get the result as an array -I tried to execute your string as following: $shellCommand=find /omd/sites/mesh/etc/icinga/conf.d/objects -name '*.cfg' \ -execdir grep -r -i -l 'host{' \{} + <br />

exec($shellCommand, $hostname);

Comment: @ThomasLang Like the other answerers, I missed the second part of your question. Maybe you should have posted _two_ separate questions? Anyway I've fixed my answer to add that part. Hope this help.

Comment: at the second look at my question I saw that I have forgotten the second part. So I added it later.
I hope this was not to confusing.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
grep -r -i --include=*.cfg 'host{' /omd/sites/mesh/etc/icinga/conf.d/objects | \
    awk '{print $1}' | sed -e 's|[^/]*/||g' -e 's|:define$||'
```

The `awk` portion finds the first field in it and the `sed` command trims off the path and the `:define`.