# Open all files present in file content search result in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is it anyway possible to open all files which found in my search query? Otherwise I need to double click 37 times for a single search result which seems suboptimal.

Example of search

[image]

Comment: You can cut in half number of clicks if you disable preview :) `"workbench.editor.enablePreview": false`

Comment: Why do you even need to open them all anyway?

Comment: @Alex because I need to change for example `position="left" anotherProp="somevalue"`and they are not in the same order or it depends on the otherprop. So a simple replace won't work

Comment: I would've just used `search.action.focusNextSearchResult` **F4** keybinding

Comment: @Alex `F4` seems interesting, but if you need to change some of the files in a way that makes them disappear from search results, the pointer is reset and `F4` starts the cycle again from the beginning.

Comment: I couldn't get F4 working for some reason. Now I just search for all files in the file system and open them all in VS Code. Really annoying that this doesn't work directly in VS Code.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As stated in @Alex's comment, **`search.action.focusNextSearchResult`** is a great match for @NealVDV's use case. It can be run by **pressing `F4`**. It will open each result one after the other in a (writable) preview tab.

- **`F4`** (**`search.action.focusNextSearchResult`**) cycles forward through the search results
- **`Shift+F4`** (**`search.action.focusPreviousSearchResult`**) cycles backward through the search results

@jakub.g makes the remark that modifying a file in a way that removes them from the search result will make the `focusNextSearchResult` pointer restart from the beginning. A solution to this issue is to make sure that either:

- The search result is never removed from the file while it is modified
- The search result is always removed from the file by the modification

Answer (score 24):

Turns out you can shift + click to highlight all the results, and then you drag them over same as any other file.  In vscode 1.71.2, at least.

I had 150 to open.  Phew.

Comment: This is the answer you are probably looking for. Thanks Cory!

Comment: In easier way to select all results, also you can use CTRL + A to select all files at once. (When focus is on results sidebar)

Answer (score 9):

There is this VS Code extension for that: [Search - Open All Results](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=fabiospampinato.vscode-search-open-all-results)

To install it, launch VS Code Quick Open (Ctrl+P) and run

`ext install fabiospampinato.vscode-search-open-all-results`

Comment: From the [plugin page](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=fabiospampinato.vscode-search-open-all-results): "There isn't really a proper API for implementing this, therefor the way this works is a bit hacky, you might find some bugs with it. Try to use this on search queries that produce 1, or very few, results per file."

Bugs indeed. Removed and resorted to hammering `search.action.focusNextSearchResult` …

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, after installing the extension, I ran a search with 150 files with roughly 15 hits per file. However when I press `CTRL+P` and type: `>Open All Results`, it will loop over the first ~10 hits only. So I tried: `"searchOpenAllResults.fileResultsLimit": 300,` and re-loading the VScode. That did not change the behaviour.  Do you know how to make it open all results instead?

Comment: Note, I added the settings incorrectly, I should have included the settings in the pre-existing `.vscode` settings `json`, instead of adding them as  a new separate dictionary. More details [here](https://github.com/fabiospampinato/vscode-search-open-all-results/issues/4#issuecomment-1302276969)

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure how to do this with a VSCode native tool, but you could do this using VSCode terminal to find the pattern that you're looking for and open all files that match your search pattern. Something like the following:

```
grep -l "<Icon" * | xargs code
```

- grep to look for your *regex pattern* with [-l parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6637894/7183373) to show only the filename.
- `xargs` to pass the output as the argument for `code`.

This way you won't have to double click all the files one-by-one.

Comment: On Windows, from Powershell, with VScode 1.42.1, this opens a single new VSCode window, **without any file opened in it**.

Comment: Try this if you only want to open files with certain name:                                                                      find . -iname CMakeLists.txt | xargs code

Answer (score 3):

You can use the up/down arrow keys to highlight the file in the search results.  Then press the right arrow and it will open the file without closing the search results.  So you basically have to press down arrow, right arrow 37 times instead of clicking.  Not great, but still faster.

Answer (score 1):

You can shift + click to select all results in the search panel. (Alternatively you can press cmd/ctrl + A multiple times until all results are selected).

Then, you can drag all results into an open editor window and all files will be opened in separate tabs within the window.

At that point, you can search all the open files in the search panel by clicking the little book icon next to the "files to include" field.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me on MacOS:

- Click one of the files from the result list
- Press Cmd+A twice to select all the files
- Drag the selected files to an editor workspace on the right

Hope it helps someone else.