# How can I pen ALL files returned by file name search in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

If I search filenames (*not* file contents) for files containing a string, e.g. `Mutation.js` and VS Code returns 30 results, how can I open ALL those files in one shot without clicking one and repeating it 30 times?

Comment: note to readers: for file content search, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/47221523/11107541

Answer (score 0):

you can use this extension on your vsCode : [OpenMatchingFiles](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bcanzanella.openmatchingfiles)

You can find how to use it in the link provided.

Comment: already tried that one and it appears to open files returned in file *contents* search, i.e. CTRL+SHIFT+F -- I need it to open files returned in file *name* search, CTRL+SHIFT+N.

Comment: @KirkRoss Are you sure? It looks like what you want, although I haven't tried it.  You trigger a filename search first with its command and then enter your search/glob and enter to confirm.  [Worst gif demo I have ever seen though.]

Comment: Works perfectly for me to do what the OP is requesting. Pass the glob pattern `**/Dockerfile` to the extension, opens all the Dockerfiles in my repo