# How to find a line of code and delete that line from all files in a certain /directory only, using Linux CLI

Tags: linux

So I used this to find all files in /directory that contain a code "test"

`grep -R “test” /directory`

Now I want to delete that code found in all the files in /directory at once.

Just that line of code for each file it is detected in.

UPDATE ***

I want to remove injected code `@require(dirname(__FILE__).'/php/malware.php');`

So this was done but it doesnt work. No error message shows. It just accepts the command.

`grep -l -R '@require(dirname(__FILE__).'/php/malware.php');' /directory | xargs -I {} sed -i.bak 's/@require(dirname(__FILE__).'/php/malware.php');//g' {}`

Comment: Should it delete the whole line? if the line contains your `test` or just the `test` and keep the rest of the line as it is?

Comment: Interesting consideration. Probably will need for future reference. How would the format look like for  just deleting `test` on a line of code instead of the entire line?

Comment: I will answer hereunder, last but not least do you have filenames with space in the middle?

Comment: Nope. Was told never to do that. Either underscore or alloneword only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following command if you want to *remove only the **`test` pattern** of your files instead of deleting the whole line what will in most of the cases break your code*:

```
grep -l -R 'test' /directory | xargs -I {} sed -i.bak 's/test//g' {}
```

It will replace globally the test pattern by nothing and also take a backup of your files while doing the operations! You never know :-)

If you are *sure that you can delete the **whole line** containing the `test` pattern* then you can use sed in the following way:

```
grep -l -R 'test' /directory | xargs -I {} sed -i.bak '/test/d' {}
```

You can after look for the backup files and delete them if they are not required anymore by using the following command:

```
find /directory -type f -name '*.bak' -exec rm -i {} \;
```

You can remove the `-i` after the `rm` if you do not need confirmation while deleting the files.

Answer (score 8):

Should pipe filenames to [sed](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sed):

```
grep -l -R “test” /directory | xargs -I {} sed -i '/test/d' {}
```

Where:

- *-l* indicates grep to print [just filenames](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6637894/520275)
- */test/d* is sed [command to delete lines matching](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5410784/520275) *test* pattern
- *-i* tells sed to write results to the same file, otherwise will just shoes output

Comment: Great answer, if he wants to delete the whole line containing `test`.  However he should use `sed` in replacement mode and change each line containing the `test` by an adequate replacement (eventually using back-reference) if he just want to remove the `test` part of the line and keep the rest of the line as-is. Finally, I would change the `-i` to `-i.bak` in order to keep a back up of the files just in case you know