# How do I get the dates of files in my output from a grep search?

Tags: file, date, grep, timestamp, output

I can search through all my files for a specific string and output in a txt document without issue. I can't seem to figure out how to also capture the date of the files in the output results.

```
grep -rnw '/my_path/' -e 'search_string' > list.txt
```

That works for finding the files, but when I try piping any additional commands like stat, date, or ls I can't seem to get the date of the files to output with file names.

```
grep -rnw '/my_path/' -e 'search_string' | stat -c %n':'%z > list.txt
```

This does not seem to work to get the dates of the files in my output.

Comment: What's the output supposed to look like?

Comment: You don't have to (or actually should not) update the question to include a solution; the solution lives in a separate answer, and you should accept and/or upvote it instead of editing the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `grep` is outputting the line that match your string, not the file name, so that in your second example your trying to call `stat` on a string, not on a file!

[You should add a `-l` parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6637882/how-can-i-use-grep-to-show-just-filenames-on-linux) to your `grep` command in order to not output the matching line but the file that contains it. Try this:

```
grep -lrnw '/my_path/' -e 'search_string' | stat -c %n':'%z > list.txt
```

[EDIT] Anyway this would not work because the `stat` command does not accept input from a pipe. The solution is then

```
stat -c %n':'%z $(grep -lrnw '/my_path/' -e 'search_string') > list.txt
```

Comment: Okay! solution worked along with your version.
grep -lrnw '/path/' -e 'string' | xargs stat -c %n':'%z > file.txt

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution with `find -exec` that avoids unquoted expansions:

```sh
find /my_path \
    -type f \
    -exec grep -qw 'search_string' {} \; \
    -exec stat -c '%n:%z' {} +
```

where

- `type f` – only look at files
- `-exec grep -qw 'search_string' {} \;` – only pass files that contain the word `search_string` to the next command
- `-exec stat -c '%n:%z' {} +` – run `stat` as few times as possible for the files found

Comment: Thank you for helping with the alternative find command. I was hoping to have both of them, and that works. They both ran identical times on my tests - but now I have 2 ways to modify.